# Reading table data properly in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I'm currently practicing with Laravel, and running into a problem where the sql query is reading everything from my second table as an array, rather than the column it should be assigned to.

I have a packages table, and a resources table to fill those packages. Package name and price work fine, but when I need to read from resources, I get this:

```
[{"id":2,"resource":"Vegetarian menu","package_id":2,"created_at":"2022-06-18T19:34:48.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-18T19:34:48.000000Z"},{"id":3,"resource":"Standard Menu","package_id":2,"created_at":"2022-06-18T19:35:31.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-18T19:35:31.000000Z"}]
```

When it really should be just "Vegetarian menu", and "Standard Menu"

What am I doing wrong?

//package model

```
class Package extends Model { use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function resources()

{
    return $this->hasMany(Resource::class);
} }
```

//package controller

```
class PackageController extends Controller {public function index(){
// SELECT * FROM packages
 $packages = Package::with('resources')->get();

 return view('service', compact('packages')); } }
```

//resource model

```
class Resource extends Model {
 use HasFactory;

 protected $fillable = ['package_id', 'resource'];

 public function package()

{
    return $this->belongsTo(Package::class);
} }
```

// UI Page

```
@foreach ($packages as $package)

        <div class="tile is-parent"><!-- each child tile needs it's own parent -->
            <article class="tile is-child box has-text-centered">
                <figure class="image is-96x96 is-inline-block">
                    <img class="is-rounded" src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="">
                </figure>

                <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">{{ $package->name }}</p>
                
                <h4 class="is-size-5 has-text-centered">£{{ number_format($package->cost) }}.00</h4>

                 <div class="content">
                 
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{ $package->resources }}</li>
                    </ul>
                
                </div><!-- content -->

            </article>
        </div><!-- parent -->
    
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly getting what you are requesting. A collection of resources associated with every package.

```php
[
 {
  "id":2,
  "resource":"Vegetarian menu",
  "package_id":2,
  "created_at":"2022-06-18T19:34:48.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2022-06-18T19:34:48.000000Z"
 },

 {
  "id":3,
  "resource":"Standard Menu",
  "package_id":2,
  "created_at":"2022-06-18T19:35:31.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2022-06-18T19:35:31.000000Z"
  }
]
```

If you want to limit the fields on the resource relation then you should modify  your query as

```php
class PackageController extends Controller {

  public function index(){

   // SELECT * FROM packages eager loads resource name and package_id
  
   $packages = Package::with('resources:resource,package_id')->get();

   return view('service', compact('packages')); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped narrow down the query results and show only the resource list

Answer (score 1):

you just need to loop through the related collection

```
@foreach ($packages as $package)

    <div class="tile is-parent"><!-- each child tile needs it's own parent -->
        <article class="tile is-child box has-text-centered">
            <figure class="image is-96x96 is-inline-block">
                <img class="is-rounded" src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="">
            </figure>

            <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">{{ $package->name }}</p>
            
            <h4 class="is-size-5 has-text-centered">£{{ number_format($package->cost) }}.00</h4>

             <div class="content">
             
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($package->resources as $r)
                      <li>{{ $r->resource }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            
            </div><!-- content -->

        </article>
    </div><!-- parent -->

@endforeach
```